# Is it possible to embed font files into html just like css?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, fonts, font-face

In a project I work on, I need to generate a one page HTML file which contains everything inside it (JavaScript code, CSS, Images, etc.). So, there should be no outside references.

I am also planning to use Bootstrap but I am not sure if it is possible to embed font files inside HTML just like CSS.

Any idea?

Comment: Are you allowed to use `<style></style>` in your HTML file?

Comment: Have you tried embedding the font in your CSS as a data: URI?

Comment: @TheSpooniest as said, there should be no outside reference.

Comment: @D4V1D hmm, obviously :) how would I embed CSS otherwise?

Comment: Right, I was going to advice you to link your font files directly in the `CSS` of your `HTML` file but then, I remembered your `should be no outside references` requirement :). I guess embedding as a `base64` encoded is the only solution

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Yes, that's actually possible. You can embed the font as a base64 encoded font like this:

```
@font-face{
    font-family: FontName;
    src: url(data:font/ttf;base64,THESTRING… ) format('truetype');
}
```

But it's not advisable as the base64 string can get rather big and cause performance issues.

Comment: yes, this is what I want! thx! I wouldn't do this is if it was actually for a web page but a tool will generate an HTML report and everything needs to be in it.

Comment: the problem was that I didn't know whether this is possible but now I kinow :)

Answer (score 12):

Yes you can. You must convert your font to a BASE64 byte and embed with Data URI, like this:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'yourfontname';
    src: url(data:application/x-font-woff;charset=utf-8;base64,**your base64 here**) format('woff');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

You can use this site to convert your font to Base64:
[Base64 encoder](http://www.opinionatedgeek.com/dotnet/tools/base64encode/)